# Javascript not working on a php while cycle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to execute this javascript code on each database table record.
I have try to define all the div id on the script, but since i am not good a javascript i can not find where is the problem.

I think that javascript should be specified with a uniq name... heres the code:

```
echo '<script>';
echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
echo 'var menu = $("#shfaqa'.$row["id"].'")';
echo '$("#butoni'.$row["id"].'").click(function(event){';
echo 'event.preventDefault();';
echo 'event.stopPropagation();';
echo 'if (menu.is(":visible"))';
echo '{';
echo 'menu.slideUp(400);';
echo 'jwplayer( "my-video'.$row["id"].'" ).stop();';
echo '}';
echo 'else';
echo '{';
echo 'menu.slideDown(400);';
echo '}';
echo '});';
echo '$(document).not("#shfaqa'.$row["id"].', #butoni'.$row["id"].'").click(function(event) {';
echo 'event.preventDefault();';
echo 'if (menu.is(":visible"))';
echo '{';
echo 'menu.slideUp(400);';
echo 'jwplayer( "my-video'.$row["id"].'" ).stop();';
echo '}';
echo '});';
echo '})';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Why do you echo everything line by line?

Comment: because is inside a php 'while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ '

Comment: @MobileSolutions: That’s no reason. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php – that makes for much cleaner syntax.

Comment: CBroe is right, it could be written using one single echo. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a ; at line 3. This should be better:

```
echo 'var menu = $("#shfaqa'.$row["id"].'");';
```

And you're missing a semicolon at the very end as well:

```
echo '});';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
```

But this whole concept has some issues as Implant said

And you could write this whole thing by just using one single echo. Much clearer, isn't it?

```
echo "<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var menu = $(\"#shfaqa{$row["id"]}\");
        $(\"#butoni{$row["id"]}\").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            if (menu.is(\":visible\"))
            {
                menu.slideUp(400);
                jwplayer( \"my-video{$row["id"]}\" ).stop();
            }
            else
            {
                menu.slideDown(400);
            }
        });
        $(document).not(\"#shfaqa{$row["id"]}, #butoni{$row["id"]}\").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (menu.is(\":visible\"))
            {
                menu.slideUp(400);
                jwplayer( \"my-video{$row["id"]}\" ).stop();
            }
        });
    });
</script>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the full javascript in a regular HTML format and echo only the PHP values you need like :

```
<?php
// any PHP condition here
if($something) {
?>
<script>
var something = <?php echo $row["id"]; ?>;
// more javascript here
</script>
<?php
}; // close php if
?>
```